# Python erro na função Def _init_ ao criar um ChatBot

Tags: python, python-3.x, chatbot

```
class wppbot:
    dir_path = os.getcwd()
    bot.def __init__(self, nome_bot):
        self.bot = ChatBot(nome_bot)
        self.bot.set_trainer(ListTrainer)
        self.chrome = self.dir_path+'\chromedriver.exe'
        self.options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        self.options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir="+self.dir_path+"\profile\wpp")
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(self.chrome, chrome_options=self.options)
```

Estou com um erro nessa parte do código, diz que há um erro de sintaxe no bot.def. Estou aprendendo agora, então qualquer ajuda é bem vinda.

Comment: O que seria esse "`bot.`" antes de `def` na terceira linha?

Comment: Ah, acho que entendi. O erro é porque não tem nada no bot? Peguei essa parte já assim.

Comment: Não, porque a sintaxe do Python está errada mesmo: https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remova a parte da terceira linha onde há

```
bot.def __init__(self, nome_bot):
```

Essa sintaxe está errada, [veja](http://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/classes.html).